# django python google distance matrix api json question

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3

so, I'm new to python and Django. I created a view and html page for a very basic form that uses the google distance matrix api. I'm able to display the output of the json back to my html page without any issues. the question is, how do I get the distance in miles to appear on my html page. Right now I'm just getting the raw json. but I can't seem to get just the distance in miles.

Current output from the HTML page:

```
    origin ['660 Celebration Ave, Celebration, FL 34747, USA']

    destination ['878 Columbus Ave, New York, NY 10023, USA']

    distance in miles: [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '1,093 mi', 'value': 1759428}, 
   'duration': {'text': '16 hours 13 mins', 'value': 58364}, 'status': 'OK'}]}]
```

'''
views.py

```
def mapdistance_view(request):
distance = {}

if 'From' in request.GET:
    origin = request.GET['From']
    destination = request.GET['To']
    apikey = "mykey"
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?mode=driving&units=imperial&origins=' + origin + ',DC&destinations=' + destination + ',' + apikey      
    response = requests.get(url)
    distance = response.json()
    print(url)
    print(distance)
return render(request, 'mapdistance.html', {'distance': distance})
```

'''

Html page
'''

```
   {% block content %}
   <h2>map API</h2>
    <form method="GET"> {% csrf_token %}
   <label>Pickup Location:</label><input type="text" name="From"><br>
   <label>Delivery Location:</label><input type="text" name="To"><br>
   <button type="submit">post to google map</button>
   </form>
   {% if distance %}
   <p><strong>origin {{ distance.origin_addresses }}</strong></p>
   <p><strong>destination {{ distance.destination_addresses }}</strong></p>
       <p><strong>distance in miles: {{ distance.rows }}</strong></p>
  {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to index JSON in Html but you could do something like this. 
First I added an id to the paragraph that contains the distance in miles. 
Then I imported jquery and nested it into script tags. 
In jquery, select the id paragraph and change the content inside to the json object index.

Below is a rough overview of what it should look like but it might work?
Superrrrr hacky way to index a json object and hopefully theres a cleaner way.

```
{% block content %}
<h2>map API</h2>
<form method="GET"> {% csrf_token %}
<label>Pickup Location:</label><input type="text" name="From"><br>
<label>Delivery Location:</label><input type="text" name="To"><br>
<button type="submit">post to google map</button>
</form>
{% if distance %}
<p><strong>origin {{ distance.origin_addresses }}</strong></p>
<p><strong>destination {{ distance.destination_addresses }}</strong></p>
   <p id="miles-paragraph"><strong>distance in miles: {{ distance.rows }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256- WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var value = JSON.parse("{{distance|escapejs}}");
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#miles-paragraph').html(value[0]["elements"]["distance"]["text"]);
</script>
```

Comment: I see where your going with it, but I need to find a way to do this in python server side. later on I need to take this mile value and do more mathematical functions with it. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Oh I see, maybe take that same idea of indexing response[0]['elements']['distance']['text']. Hope this helps further and good luck!